# rails parent child filtration on a record set

Tags: ruby-on-rails, tree, parent-child

I'm having a very complex query which results in a record set with lots of records. Now in Ruby on Rails I want to sort in such a way that a child comes under a parent.

Like `record_set.sort_by_relation`.

It is same table parent child relation. Child is associated with parent with parent_id.

Example: a record set having following result:

- Main Tender 1
- sub tender 21
- Main Tender 2
- sub tender 1
- sub tender 22
- sub tender 2

The desired result would be:

- Main Tender 1
- sub tender 1
- sub tender 2
- Main Tender 2
- sub tender 21
- sub tender 22

Answer (score 0):

You could get there using a gem like [Awesome Nested Set](https://github.com/collectiveidea/awesome_nested_set), with which you can implement this kind of nesting.

If you don't want to use a gem, you could consider first getting your parents using something like `where('parent_id IS NULL')` and then for each parent get its children (and its children and so on) using `where('parent_id = ?', object.id)`.

Awesome Nested Set is pretty neat though. You will be able to do something like this:

```
<ul>
  <%- record_set.roots.each do |record| %>
    <%= render :partial => 'record', :locals => {:record => record} %>
  <%- end %>
</ul>
```

_record.html.erb

```
<li>
  <%= record.name %>
  <%- unless record.children.empty? %>
    <ul>
      <%- record.children.each do |child|
        <%= render :partial => 'record', :locals => {:record => child} %>
      <%- end %>
    </ul>
  <%- end %>
</li>
```

I hope this helps :)

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. actually i need only 1 level children and  adding a new gem for only 1 level would be a lot. I can't add where('parent_id IS NULL') because it might possible child of one record may be a parent of some other record.

Comment: any database query which can pull parent and child max at one level would also be fine. But for this query we need to remember - child of one record - may be parent so some other record.

Comment: If a child can be a parent to another record, you have more than one sublevel. Think about how you would determine which nodes are the root nodes, because that's very unclear at this point. If you have that, you can create an array of root nodes and get their children accordingly.